# Make Object Edits using Action Foundry APIs

Tags: palantir-foundry

Can Foundry APIs be used to call Objects and run Actions to make Object edits on a regular schedule?

I'm seeking the following behavior on a regularly occurring schedule:

1. Pull down Objects meeting specific criteria via request API call
2. Run Actions on the pulled Objects (email Notification + Object edit)

NOTE: Logic Flows not available on the stack.

Comment: Hi, a lot of the folks from Palantir that regularly answer these questions are on hollidays  till EOY. If no one from the community answers till we're back, we'll drop you an answer then. My gut feeling tells me that you can't use foundry APIs to do these, but perhaps you can take a look at "Logic Flows" if it is available in your stack

Comment: Thanks I appreciate this - "Logic Flows" is not currently available on our deployment.

Comment: I've been told that at the moment these types of actions, even though possible, are currently very specific to each stack security configurations. So I would recommend that you reach out internally through your support channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple of ways to address these.

1 - If you want to call APIs from transforms, then there are security implications here, and I would recommend you to reach out internally through the support channels.

2 - If you just want to call APIs to perform object edits, for example from an external application. I invite you to read about Objects Gateway `https://yourstack/workspace/documentation/product/objects-gateway/overview`

There you can call functions on objects, which can in turn perform the actions you require.

> For example, to rename an employee, whose ID number is 80060 and whose
> new name is "Anna Smith-Doe", you might use the following request.

```
POST /objects-gateway/api/v1/ontologies/ri.ontology.main.ontology.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/actions/rename-employee/apply

{
    "parameters": {
        "id": 80060,
        "newName": "Anna Smith-Doe"
    }
}
```

3 - For reading an object you can use the same service to perform searches:

```
GET /objects-gateway/api/v1/ontologies/ri.ontology.main.ontology.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/objects/employee?properties.firstName.eq=John
```

Comment: Objects Gateway isn't in our stack documentation (yet). 

Can Actions be configured in the Objects Gateway to make Object Edits based on logical criteria, i.e. Action X triggers when an object bearing a specific value is recognized?

Comment: @L99 can you reach out through your support channels asking about it, to see if the service can be installed into your stack? Regarding the logic criteria, you can configure object gateway to call a an action backed by a function from Functions on Objects which can own both the logic criteria and the edit. However Functions don't run on a schedule and you would have to trigger them from somewhere, either externally from an app (via 2 || 3 above) or internally (via 1)

Comment: An Object-focused app that will address this workflow's needs will be GA ~Q3. Appreciate your help here!

Comment: L99 I just recently discovered there are also Actions webhooks that can be used to call your edit function via actions